# HTTP Post Request error HTTPError: Bad Request

Tags: python, httprequest, http-error

I am sending a HTTP POST Request.

My data consists of a dictionary with two entries:

- one value in the dictionary is a string
- the other value is an array of strings.

I know the URL is valid but I keep getting:

```
HTTPError: Bad Request
```

Can anyone identify where I am going wrong?

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

array_of_strings = ["yrrt", "rtgh", "erte", "eregee"]        
url_4 = 'http:// someurl'
data_4 ={"key": "value", "array": array_of_strings}

request_4 = Request(url_4, urlencode(data_4).encode())
response = urlopen(request_4).read().decode()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bad request can be caused by an invalid parameter or incorrect Content-Type. Make sure all request parameters are correct, your code doesn't look incorrect.

BTW, I would recommend you to use requests instead of urllib: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

This is your code using requests:

```
import requests

array_of_strings=["yrrt", "rtgh", "erte", "eregee"]........

url_4= 'https://login.locaweb.com.br/v1/tickets'
data_4={"key": "value", "array": array_of_strings}

response = requests.post(url_4, data=data_4)
print(response.text)
```

It has a simpler syntax and is easier to debug.